# formdata can only post files correctly but erase all strings. (using node, express, and multer)

Tags: node.js, express, multipartform-data, multer, form-data

I have tried to upload the formdata through node.js by multer.

once I tested to upload the files, all works well. But after I tested the strings, server can not get any information (keys, values, etc.).

On my console, I can print out the formdata correctly

```
console.log(Array.from(formData));
```

result:

```
(13) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
0: (2) ["pnum", "123"]
1: (2) ["age", "123"]
2: (2) ["gender", "male"]
3: (2) ["ethn", "Hispanic or Latino"]
4: (2) ["q1", "undefined"]
5: (2) ["q2", "123"]
6: (2) ["q3", "123"]
7: (2) ["q4", "123"]
8: (2) ["q5", "123"]
9: (2) ["q6", "123"]
10: (2) ["q7", "123"]
11: (2) ["q8", "123"]
12: (2) ["q9", "123"]
length: 13
__proto__: Array(0)
```

But once I checked on server side:

```
console.log(req.files);
```

It just returns an empty array:

```
[]
```

If I append both strings and files together into the formdata, only the files will be uploaded, the strings are still missing.

app.js:

```
routes.post('/', upload.any(), async function(req,res) {
    if (req.files) {
        console.log(req.files);
    }
})
```

frontend js:

```
console.log(Array.from(formData));
$.ajax({
    url:  window.location.href,
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false, 
    processData: false, 
    success: function(success) {
        console.log(success);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, strings in formdata are also returned to `req.body` instead of `req.files`